# Select groups of rows each with a certain value in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Say I have the following rows in a table:

```
+----+--------------+-------+------+
| ID | fruit        | amount| price|
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  1 | oranges      |     7 |  20  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  2 | plums        |     21|  32  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  3 | oranges      |     2 |  32  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  4 | oranges      |     7 |  12  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  5 | plums        |     4 |  89  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  6 | grapes       |     5 |  34  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+ 
|  7 | grapes       |     6 |  132 |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
|  8 | plums        |     2 |  19  |
+----+--------------+-------+------+
```

My end goal is to get total amounts and total prices for each unique fruit in a table.

Right now, the sequence of functions I was thinking of doing to get the desired effect is:

```
using PHP: SELECT * from table where fruit = "oranges".
```

I will be using ajax to run this so I was going to use jquery to add the amount and price. Then repeat for "plums" and "grapes".

One of the issues i'll have is I won't know what fruits will be in the fruit table.

So is there a simpler way to find all unique fruits in the column, then search the database for rows with each of those fruits and then add totals for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the grouped result and then iterate over it for display

```
select fruit, sum(amount), sum(amount*price)
from table 
group by fruit
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this mean I would have to run this query several times for each fruit? (even though I wont know which fruits there are?)

Comment: @Bruno no you need  perform this query one time only and then simply iterare over the result with a  while loop  until you have rows and display one row in each loop

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Would that query give me the sum of all oranges, sum of all plums etc?

Comment: The query return a set of rows one for each distinct fruit and in each row you have the fruit name, the amount of this fruit and the sum of each amount*price related to this fruit ..

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much, much appreciated!