# MySQL How to apply WHERE clause to all selected columns except one?

Tags: mysql

I am totalling columns and grouping them by a column "fruits" like this: (based on my [previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878211/select-groups-of-rows-each-with-a-certain-value-in-mysql))

```
SELECT `fruits`, sum(amount), sum(price)
FROM `accounts` 
GROUP BY fruits
```

I have now added a date column to the table and i'm trying to filter the result by dates like this:

```
SELECT `fruits`, sum(amount), sum(price)
FROM `accounts` 
WHERE `userid` = 1 AND `date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22"
GROUP BY fruits
```

This works fine and I get the filtered results. However, if a fruit has not been entered between the two dates, it naturally doesn't show up because the WHERE clause also includes the `fruits`.

So, my question is how can I write a query where it gets all the fruits regardless of the dates but filters only the amount and price column by dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a left join:

```
SELECT t.`fruits`,sum(coalesce(s.amount,0)),sum(coalesce(s.price,0))
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT `fruits` FROM `accouts`) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` s
 ON(t.`fruits` = s.`fruits` AND s.`userid` = 1
    AND s.`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22")
GROUP BY t.`fruits`
```

Comment: No problem @Bruno :)

Answer (score 2):

Theres' a couple of approaches. One is to use conditional aggregation.  Remove the predicate, and move the conditional test to an expression in the SELECT list.  For example, something like this:

```
SELECT a.fruits
     , SUM( IF(a.userid = 1 AND a.date BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2015-12-22'
              ,a.amount,0)
       ) AS `tot_amount`
     , SUM( IF(a.userid = 1 AND a.date BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2015-12-22'
              ,a.price,0)
       ) AS `tot_price`
  FROM `accounts` a
 GROUP BY a.fruits
```

Other approaches will use a row source that returns the values of `fruits` you want returned, and then an "outer join" to the totals from your original query.  Or for a reasonably small number of rows, you could use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.

Let's say that this returns the set of `fruits` you want to returned:

```
SELECT s.fruits
  FROM `accounts` s
 GROUP BY s.fruits
```

We can wrap that in parens, and use it as a rowsource like it was a table. As a trivial example of that:

```
SELECT f.fruits
  FROM ( 
         SELECT s.fruits
           FROM `accounts` s
          GROUP BY s.fruits
       ) f
```

Now we could do the same thing with your original query, wrap it in parens and make it an inline view:

```
SELECT f.fruits
     , IFNULL(t.tot_amount,0) AS tot_amount
     , IFNULL(t.tot_price,0)  AS tot_price
  FROM ( 
         SELECT s.fruits
           FROM `accounts` s
          GROUP BY s.fruits
       ) f
  LEFT
  JOIN (  
         -- original query here 
         SELECT a.`fruits`
              , sum(a.amount) AS tot_amount
              , sum(a.price) AS tot_price
           FROM `accounts` a
          WHERE a.`userid` = 1
            AND a.`date` BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2015-12-22'
          GROUP BY a.fruits
       ) t
    ON t.fruits = f.fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `fruits`, 
    sum((`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22") * amount) total_amount,
    sum((`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22") * price) total_price
FROM `accounts` 
WHERE `userid` = 1
GROUP BY fruits
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do by this one:

```
SELECT a1.`fruits`, sum(a1.amount), sum(a1.price)
FROM `accounts` a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` a2 ON a1.fruits = a2.fruits 
AND a2.`userid` = 1 AND a2.`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22" 
GROUP BY a1.fruits
```